# Flutter Problem: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: Auth(),)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have  maked two different auth file login_auth.dart and signup_auth.dart for login and signup, But error is coming in main.dart, and only one of login_auth.dart and sign_auth.dart is being imported but I want auth of both files.

please check I do for auth in main.dart.

This is my login_auth.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Utils/api.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  var MainUrl = Api.authUrl;

  notifyListeners();

  Future<void> Authentication(String user_name, String user_email,
      String mobile_no, String password, String action) async {
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse('$MainUrl&action=$action');
      print(url);

      final responce = await http.post(url, headers: {
        "Accept": "Application/json"
      }, body: {
        "user_name": user_name,
        'user_email': user_email,
        "username": mobile_no,
        "password": password,
      });

      print("Response" + responce.body);
      final responceData = json.decode(responce.body);
      print("responceData" + responceData);

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  Future<void> login(
      String user_name, String user_email, String mobile_no, String password) {
    return Authentication(user_name, user_email, mobile_no, password, 'login');
  }
}
```

This is my signup_auth.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Utils/api.dart';

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  var MainUrl = Api.authUrl;

  Future<void> Authentication(String user_name, String user_email,
      String mobile_no, String password, String action) async {
    try {
      var url = Uri.parse('$MainUrl&action=$action');
      print(url);

      final responce = await http.post(url, headers: {
        "Accept": "Application/json"
      }, body: {
        "user_name": user_name,
        'user_email': user_email,
        "mobile_no": mobile_no,
        "password": password,
      });

      print("Response" + responce.body);
      final responceData = json.decode(responce.body);
      print("responceData" + responceData);

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  // Future<void> login(
  //     String user_name, String user_email, String mobile_no, String password) {
  //   return Authentication(user_name, user_email, mobile_no, password, 'login');
  // }

  Future<void> signUp(
      String user_name, String user_email, String mobile_no, String password) {
    return Authentication(
        user_name, user_email, mobile_no, password, 'registration');
  }
}
```

This is my main.dart page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/login_auth.dart';  //here
import 'package:login_and_signup/Providers/signup_auth.dart'; // here
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/login.dart';
import 'package:login_and_signup/Screens/splash_screen.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(                //here
      value: Auth(),                                    //here
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
        home: LoginScreen(),
      ),
          );
  }
}
```